# How to properly use jquery-mask-plugin in typescript?

Tags: jquery, typescript, asp.net-core-mvc, mask

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC project that needs to have masks on some inputs.

I installed the [jquery-mask-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-mask-plugin) using the instructions for Typescript, so just used this in the console:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery-mask-plugin
```

When I try to use the code

```
$("#inputID").mask('AAAAAAAAAA');
```

in the app, I get this error in devtools when running the project:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mask is not a function

Am I using this wrong because it is typescript? My version is 4.1.3

Comment: How did you include the plugin in your application? npm install is not enough alone,

Comment: Does jquery-mask-plugin load in your page? Or you can try to use the cdn node to see if it works.